# How to add metadata to a new subscription in Stripe?

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I have this code, from the examples on Stripe API docs site:

```
stripe.Key = "my_key"

s, err := sub.New(&stripe.SubParams{
    Customer: "test_customer",
    Plan: "month-plan",

})
```

This code works just fine. But I couldn't find how to add metadata to this request, like `Product: "special-services"`.

Can I do it in one request on subscription creation, and if so, then how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
subParams := &stripe.SubParams{
    Customer: "test_customer",
    Plan: "month-plan",
}
subParams.AddMeta("Product","special-services")
s, err := sub.New(subParams)
```

[`stripe.SubParams`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stripe/stripe-go#SubParams) embeds [`stripe.Params`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stripe/stripe-go#Params) which has a method [`AddMeta`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stripe/stripe-go#Params.AddMeta), which adds meta info to a `map[string]string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach also:

```
subParams := &stripe.SubParams{
Customer: "test_customer",
Plan: "month-plan",
Params: stripe.Params{
    Metadata: map[string]string{
        "Product": "special-services",
    },
  },
}
s, err := sub.New(subParams)
```